# Java load encrypted private key

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, rsa, private-key

I have spent too long looking for a solution that can load an encrypted private key generated automatically by openssl cert creation.

Generate certificate and new private key with pass-phrase: `password`

```sh
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -x509 -keyout test.key -out test.crt -days 365
```

I have extracted the important part of the code

```java
package test;

import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.AlgorithmParameters;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@Log4j2
class pkShould {
    
    private static final String PASS_PHRASE = "password";

    @SneakyThrows
    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Path pKPath = Paths.get(cl.getResource("keystore/test.key").toURI());
        try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(pKPath)) {
            String encrypted = lines.collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            encrypted = encrypted.replace("-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
            encrypted = encrypted.replace("-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
            byte[] content = Base64.decode(encrypted);

            EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptPKInfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(content);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());
            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(PASS_PHRASE.toCharArray());
            SecretKeyFactory secFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());
            Key pbeKey = secFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
            AlgorithmParameters algParams = encryptPKInfo.getAlgParameters();
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, algParams);
            KeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = encryptPKInfo.getKeySpec(cipher);
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PrivateKey expectedPrivateKey = kf.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);
        }
    }
}
```

Never makes it past `EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo`, as far as I can tell the private key formed correctly and it is working fine used in a keyStore.

Stacktrace

```
java.io.IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)

    at sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier.<init>(ObjectIdentifier.java:285)
    at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getOID(DerInputStream.java:321)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES2Parameters.engineInit(PBES2Parameters.java:267)
    at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.init(AlgorithmParameters.java:293)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.decodeParams(AlgorithmId.java:150)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.<init>(AlgorithmId.java:132)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.parse(AlgorithmId.java:416)
    at javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:95)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is extremely useless, unfortunately. All it really means is 'java did not like it'. It can mean almost anything from: The key is protected with a passphrase cipher and/or bitsize that java doesn't like, to the key itself is using a cipher/bitsize java doesn't like, to the key is in a format that isn't PKCS#8.

It sure looks like you generated the key in x509 format, which probably isn't going to work. Perhaps converting it will work; give this a try:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 \ 
-inform PEM -outform PEM \ 
-in key.pem -out key-pkcs8.pem
```

Comment: That did it... how is it even possible to make an x509 private key, I assumed `-x509` applied only to the `-out test.crt`. I obviously need to read up on this more.

Comment: @Matthew.Lothian: you're correct, there's really no such thing as an X.509 private key. Some openssl commands create keys in their own formats instead of more standard ones. Don't blame openssl, they've been around longer than Java!

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: actually, `openssl req -newkey -keyout` does create PKCS8, as confirmed by the PEM labels `BEGIN/END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY`. But it uses a PBES2 scheme, and Java below 8u301 or 11.0.1 has a bug that misparses PBES2 parameters; see numerous other Qs for "data isn't an object ID (tag=48)" (which BTW identifies exactly this problem and no other). `openssl pkcs8 -topk8` _in 1.0.x_ defaults to a (badly insecure!) PBES1 scheme Java can handle, but if you use e.g. `-v2 aes128` or OpenSSL 1.1.x it will produce the same problem.