# Caused by: java.io.IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat

[image]

' server.ssl.key-store = src/main/resources/laitadmin.p12 server.ssl.key-alias= 1 server.ssl.keyStoreType= PKCS12'

```
'   at sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier.<init>(ObjectIdentifier.java:257) ~[na:1.8.0_251]'
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your keystore is either corrupt or uses an algorithm that Java does not support. Please post the steps you used to generate the keystore, your Java version(s), and the output of `keytool -list -v laitadmin.p12`.

Comment: Dupe: see multiple links at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70244066/keytool-error-java-io-ioexception-parsealgparameters-failed-objectidentifier

Answer (score 6):

AES encryption in pkcs12 is not supported in java up to java 11. This is a known issue.
Reference - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8220734

Comment: Also fixed in 8u301 (and 7u311 for paid support), see #8214513 (linked from page you link) also #8202837

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I solved it by exporting again by MS Edge, but now using the `TripleDES-SHA1` Cryptography option on Windows export certified wizard.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to `openssl3` `PKCS12` using `PBES2 cipher` which is unsupported in java 8 (at least under 8u301).

Simply install `openssl1.1` and use that instead to generate p12 file.

For example in macos,

- `brew install openssl@1.1`
- `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1t/bin/openssl pkcs12 -inkey cert.pkey -in cert.pem -export -out cert.p12`